# This question appears to be off-topic because [custom ending]

Tags: discussion, comments, off-topic

I've seen a lot of comments in which people provide their own ending to this sentence. I'm confused by this practice. It gives the comment a slightly more official appearance, as it appears to be similar to the pre-written comments that I see when I flag a question.

Is it considered good practice to write your own "custom" off-topic messages? When other people write them, does it mean that the question has been flagged, or is it just a normal comment?

**edit**: I think that [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185867/253499) clarifies that this is an option available to users with sufficient reputation to cast close votes.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186026/the-other-off-topic-reason-for-closing-can-circumvent-our-actual-mission?rq=1

Comment: The option automatically pops up when you choose "other" when closing as Off-Topic, so it is something encouraged by the system. (The point is that what you enter as the custom close reason can be selected by later voters)

Comment: I usually use this option in the Close Vote menu when a question is off-topic, but might be on-topic on another SE site that is not in the standard list of migration targets.

Comment: In a word: **yes**. More in depth, it's a way to give a more specific wording to a generic title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an option when closing a question to close a question with a custom reason.  When doing so, the given text is populated by default (although it can be overwritten).

[image]

Comment: I don't have this option on Stack Overflow. Is this something that becomes available with a higher rep? If so, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @TomFenech It is available to every user with the privilege to vote to close.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the distinction; flag vs. vote.

Comment: I think that would explain why I don't see the option then. I don't have 3K rep. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Tom http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @AaronBertrand That doesn't document the use of the custom close reason, just the ability to vote to close.

Comment: @Servy His question was ambiguous - I assumed he wanted to know where it was documented that 3K is required to vote to close (regardless of the reason, custom or not).

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the link. I was asking whether the fact that you could write your own message was documented. The reason for the entire question was that I didn't know that leaving this kind of message was an official site feature. I thought that people might have just been leaving comments written in this style.

Comment: @Tom some background and plenty of discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118444/add-a-custom-close-reason and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons

Answer (score 4):

> Is it considered good practice to write your own "custom" off-topic messages?

If none of the default messages seem to suit the reason then sure, after all, that's why it's there. They try to do a good job of getting the most relevant/common messages in there but they obviously can't cover them all.

> When other people write them, does it mean that the question has been flagged, or is it just a normal comment?

It is a vote to close just as if they had voted to close as a dupe, off-topic "should be on another site", etc...