# How do I review this low quality post with a custom off-topic message?

Tags: feature-request, review, custom-close-reasons

[As I recently discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227102/this-question-appears-to-be-off-topic-because-custom-ending), users with more than 3K reputation are able to provide their own custom off-topic message. When I (just a 2K user) am reviewing low quality posts, I sometimes see things like this:

> [image: It's a custom off-topic reason!]

If I click "Recommend Close", the custom off-topic message is not on the list. So what option should I choose?

I agree that all users shouldn't be able to write their own off-topic messages, but wouldn't it make sense to allow reviewers of low quality posts to agree with ones that already exist when recommending to close?

Comment: Agreed the current mechanism is annoying. Since the custom message exists only in comments (it's not displayed in the actual close banner once question is closed) you can write something like "what he said" then delete the auto comment right away. :)